# Executing a node-webkit application from vscode

Tags: json, node.js, node-webkit, visual-studio-code

I am testing node-webkit in vscode, but I am having issues executing it.

In my launch.json file I have this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "index.html",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": ".",
            "runtimeExecutable": "/home/ryan/nwjs/nw",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

> cannot launch program '/home/ryan/Test/index.html'; enabling source maps might help

From the commandline I would run this:

```
/home/ryan/nwjs/nw /home/ryan/Test
```

And it runs the application just fine.

So, am I setting this up wrong or something?

Comment: I switched to electron which does work from within vscode.